# CORS Error on browser back button

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a ASP.NET Web API 2 Service. And multiple client(angular) applications talks to that service. the applications and the service are published on different sub domains, like the following:

> service.mydomain.com
>
> app1.mydomain.com
>
> app2.mydomain.com

I used Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors - NuGet package to enable CORS, it is working fine, except for one scenario:
When the user opens one application (app1.mydomain.com). 
Then navigates to another (app2.mydomain.com). Then presses the browser back button. the follwoing CORS Error:

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://app2.mydomain.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. 
Origin 'http://app1.mydomain.com' is therefore not allowed access
```

I Configured The Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors - NuGet package, as follows:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
                //to-do allow cross domains for all maarif.com sites
                origins: "*", //and also tried "http://app1.mydomain.com, http://app2.mydomain.com" gives same result
                headers: "*",
                methods: "*") {SupportsCredentials = true};

            config.EnableCors(cors);
        }
```

I traced the Origin header values on the server.
I put the following code in the service 'global.asax' :

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            var origin = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Origin"];

            if (origin != null )
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            }
        }
```

The problem happens when user clicks back button form 'app2.mydomain.com' to 'app1.mydomain.com', the origin sent with the request is 'app2.mydomain.com', and there that is what the service allows access to: `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'app2.mydomain.com');`

Any Way around this?

Note that I can't put '*' because the requests are authenticated.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is due to the cache mechanism of browser. Because the browser would use the data from cache, even for AJAX request, when you clicked the BACK button.

For this, the browser wouldn't resend the CORS preflight to check the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for the origin of previous page. Then it would use the latest `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, which is the `app2.mydomain.com`, so that the `app1.mydomain.com` should fail.

A simple solution is adding a timestamp or a random string at the end of the api querystring, for example:

#### js:

```
let url = 'https://service.mydomain.com/xxxxx?v=' + Date.now();
```

However it would ignore `Access-Control-Max-Age`, which makes a CORS preflight every request to the `service.mydomain.com`.

Or you can force opening all links to other origin in a new window, so that there is no BACK actions could be done.

Except these, I can not find any other solutions.

**Updated:**

I tested later after this anwser, and then found the final solution:

Add following HTTP response headers in the `service.mydomain.com`, and then all is ok.

#### http:

```
Cache-Control: no-store,no-cache,must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
```

Just disable all cache of the AJAX requests. And the CORS Max-age works too.

Now it works in Chrome and Firefox. I didn't try other browsers, but I think it should be nothing different.

Comment: My solution is to add the host in the query string (e.g. ?host=app1.domain.com) so that the other domain won't get the cached response.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to put in your StratUp.cs file something like:

```
var corsPolicy = new CorsPolicy
            {
                AllowAnyMethod = true,
                AllowAnyHeader = true,
                SupportsCredentials = true,
                Origins = { "http://site1.example.com", "http://site2.emaple.com.:38091", "http://localhost:39372" }

            };

            app.UseCors(new CorsOptions
            {
                PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
                {
                    PolicyResolver = context => Task.FromResult(corsPolicy)
                }
            });
```

And in your web.config in your webserver section maybe like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Actually I am using, the Web Api project uses 'global.asax' file not 'StratUp.cs'
I tried to HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "app1.mydomain.com, app2.mydomain.com");

Comment: ok how you prefer ... but have you tried to do like i suggest to you? .. does it  work?

Comment: I put it like this: HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow‌​-Origin", "app1.mydomain.com, app2.mydomain.com");  but it is not working, it does not accept multiple domains in the header value, the error says it has to be single domain

Comment: this is why i suggest to you..to give a try to my solution... don't put it in the header how you're doing... but try with other way .. and then you set in you web config the scodn part of my answer (i'll edit now)

Comment: I tried to use Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors Nuget  Package, and configured it like: 
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
                //to-do allow cross domains for all maarif.com sites
                origins: "http://app1.mydomain.com, app2.mydomain.com",
                headers: "*",
                methods: "*") {SupportsCredentials = true};
            
            config.EnableCors(cors);
It works in all scenarios except for browser back form domain2 to domain1 it gives error

Comment: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://app2.mydomain.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. 
Origin 'app1.mydomain.com' is therefore not allowed access